# If the order of $G$ is odd, show that for any $y \in G$ there is a unique $x \in G$ such that $x^2=y$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This question seems to be a typical one, but I am not sure about the uniqueness part.

My attempt

> Suppose $|G|$ is odd. By Lagrange's Theorem, we have all elements in $G$ is of odd order. In particular, there is no element of order $2$, i.e. $x^2 \ne e$ for all $x \in G$. Then by closure of a group $x^2=y$ for some $y \in G$. In other words, for any $y \in G$ there exist $x \in G$ such that $x^2=y$.

How can I show such $x$ is unique?

Comment: You've show that for some $y$, we have $x^2 = y$. But the claim you're supposed to show is that *given* a fixed value of $y$, there is *some* $x$ with $x^2 = y$ -- to put it differently: you've shown that *one* element has a square root; you're supposed to show that *every* element has one. Also: I don't see a request for a proof of uniqueness in the problem stated, so why are you concerned about it?

Comment: Sorry. I missed the word unique in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You've got the right idea using Lagrange's theorem, but your execution is not quite right, as pointed out by John Hughes. Instead, you might consider proving the more general fact: suppose $n$ is coprime to the order of $G$. Then the map $x \mapsto x^{n}$ from $G$ to itself is bijection. You'll want to use Bezout's lemma, as well as the fact that $G$ is finite. This establishes both existence and uniqueness of the $x$ you're looking for. One should carefully note that this map is not a homomorphism in general. Feel free to comment if you need more details.

Comment: The map $\phi (x) = x^n$ is a homomorphism if and only if $G$ is abelian. But the question didn't say that $G$ is abelian.

Comment: Actually, without having $\phi(x) = x^2$ to be a homomorphism. I can show that the map $\phi$ is bijective. So the uniqueness part can be done as follow: 
Suppose $x^2 = g = y^2$. Note that $gcd(2,|G|)=1$ implies there exists $a, b \in \mathbb Z$ such that  $2a+|G|b=1$. Since $x^{|G|}=y^{|G|}=e$, we have $$x=x^{2a+|G|b}=(x^2)^a=(y^2)^a=y^{2a+|G|b}=y$$ It follows that such $x$ is unique.
But I still don't understand how the bijective map shows existence?

Comment: Yes, the point being that it does not matter that $\phi$ is not a homomorphism. Bijective shows existence via surjectivity; for any $y \in G$, there is an $x \in G$ such that $\phi(x) = x^{2} = y$.

Comment: So the existence part should be done in this way:
Suppose $|G|$ is odd. By Lagrange's Theorem, we have there is no element of order $2$, i.e. $x^2 \ne e$ for all $x \in G$. Then by closure of a group $x^2=y$ for some $y \in G$. Since the map $\phi (x) = x^n$ is sujective. It follows that for any $y \in G$, there exists an $x \in G$ such that $x^2=y$.

Am I right?